# Capture video stream frames from raspberry pi and save in jpgs

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer

I must start by saying I am a fish out of water when it comes to using gstreamer and linux in general so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm working on an ANN project that involves taking a video stream from a raspberry pi and saving the stream in a jpegs that can be used by the neural network.

So far I was able to get the pi streaming to my computer using this code here..

```
 raspivid -t 999999 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=MY_IP_ADDRESS port=5000
```

and by running this on my laptop..

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=SAME_IP port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

The problem I'm running into is I can't save the frames.

I know I need to use multifilesink to save the files but the problem is I'm so new to this I have no idea how to incorporate this into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you read the application development manual so you understand the concepts around GStreamer: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/index.html

Reading the gst-launch manual will help too to get you started on the syntax of it. You basically build your pipeline of elements and link them together using `!`.

Going into your pipeline, the receiver gets its data on a tcp connection, it will depayload the GDP format, then RTP depayloading, h264 decoding and into colorspace convertion and sending to the scree. You want to replace the screen part with saving stuff in the jpeg format. So let's replace the output part to something that would encode and save to disk:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=SAME_IP port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! queue ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=output_%05d.jpg`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the info. Got it up and running with your help